# AngularJS $http.get spinner using ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I would like to show a spinner during a `$http.get`. This is my code :

**AngularJS part :**

```
var portalSDM = angular.module('portalSDM', ['ui.router', 'agGrid', 'angular.filter', 'angularSpinkit']);

portalSDM.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state("Default", {});

    $stateProvider

    // PARTIAL MASTERPEGAWAI AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('talentapegawai', {
        views: {
            "home": {
                url: '/talentapegawai',
                templateUrl: '/partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html',
                controller: function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
                    $scope.prograssing = true;

                    $http.get('http://10.16.107.77:3333/allhistorytalenta').success(function (data) {
                        $scope.prograssing = false;
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

**NodeJS router :**

```
app.get('/talentapegawai', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

**HTML part :**

```
<a ui-sref="talentapegawai"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class=" fa fa-check"></i></button></a>
```

The spinner :

```
<wave-spinner ng-show='prograssing'></wave-spinner>
```

The spinner does not appear at all, but if I delete the `ng-show='prograssing'` the spinner does shown.

How to call the spinner in a proper way, so during the `$http.get` it will shown and after finish it will be hidden

Comment: You're starting the progress when you receive the response, instead of starting it before sending the request. I would use a finally() block to stop the progress, otherwise your spinner won't stop spinning if you have an http error. success() is deprecated, and wrapping your code with `$(function(){`is useless, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. Basically it starts loader when the before the Http call is made and ends it when the success callback is executed.

```
var portalSDM = angular.module('portalSDM', ['ui.router','agGrid','angular.filter','angularSpinkit']);

portalSDM.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider.state("Default", {});

$stateProvider

// PARTIAL MASTERPEGAWAI AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
.state('talentapegawai', {
views:{
  "home": { 
    url: '/talentapegawai',
    templateUrl: '/partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html',
    controller:function($scope,$http,$interval){
//start loader
        $scope.prograssing = true;
        $http.get('http://10.16.107.77:3333/allhistorytalenta').success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $(function(){
                var array = data;
                var res = Enumerable.From(array).GroupBy(function (x) { return x.nip + '&' + x.nama;} ).Select(function (x) { return { key: x.Key(), res:x.Aggregate(function(a,b){
                 var res={};
                 for(p in a)
                    if(p!= 'nip' && p != 'nama')
                        res[p]=a[p];
                  for(p in b)
                    if(p!= 'nip' && p != 'nama' && a[p]==null && b[p]!=null)
                        res[p]=b[p];            


                   return res;
               }) } }).ToArray().map(function(x){
                 x.res.nip=x.key.split('&')[0];
                 x.res.nama=x.key.split('&')[1];
                 return x.res;
               });
               console.log(res); 
               $scope.listtalentapegawai=res;
            })

            var column = Object.keys(data[0]);
            $scope.kolom=column;
            //stop loader
            $scope.prograssing = false;
        });
    }
  }
}
})

});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Please tell me if you are able to render the `prograssing` boolean in the view. try `{{prograssing}}` in the view to check whether the boolean is shown in view or not.

Comment: This means your view is not binded by the controller in which you are defining your `prograssing` boolean. try to debug it or edit your question and paste the complete `/partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html` which is binded by the controller. You can try injecting $rootScope and replace `$scope.prograssing` to `$rootScope.prograssing` to view the loader. But binding in its own scope is good practice.

Comment: Thank you @mJunaidSalaat, I miss placed the spinner. I put it not in /partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 controller:function($scope,$http,$interval){
          $scope.prograssing = true;
          $http.get('http://10.16.107.77:3333/allhistorytalenta')
              .success(function(data){
                   $scope.prograssing = false;                 
              });
 });
```

Comment: @AriefGrando then your spinner is probably not in the view handled by that controller. Saying "not working" is not sufficient. Edit your question, remove all the irrelevant stuff from the code, but provide all that is relevant.

Comment: Okay sir, I have update the code, please give me a review

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the scope problem. The quickest fix here is to use the `$rootScope` (which is not recommended) with an object. So change your code like this:

**In your view's controller**:

```
$rootScope.globalData = $rootScope.globalData || {};
$rootScope.globalData.prograssing = true;

$http.get('http://10.16.107.77:3333/allhistorytalenta').success(function(data) {
    $rootScope.globalData.prograssing = false;
});
```

**In your HTML:**

```
<wave-spinner ng-show="globalData.prograssing"></wave-spinner>
```

Read more on the [scope problem](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: Thank you sir, I miss placed the spinner. I put it not in /partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html

Comment: No problem. Glad it fixed :-)